# Fbox increase the spacing between the box and it content (inner margin)

Tags: spacing, boxes, framed

Is there a way to control the top and bottom spacing between the box and it content (text)? and secondary about left and right spacing? in other words i am looking for the analogous of `\arraystretch` command in this case.

PS: here `\parbox` is used to allow line breaking.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\fbox{\parbox{\linewidth}{Hello world test example break this line\\
here is a new line just for the example}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: No, not really -- `\fboxsep` is the spacing but it is used for all margins

Comment: They're all equal to `\fboxsep . The default is `3pt`, if I remember well.

Comment: If you want also the frame to break across pages, you can use the  `framed` environment.

Comment: So if I change the value/length of fboxsep all fbox will be affected, unless i do it locally with groups {} is that possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, `\fbox` and the underlying `\fr@meb@x` use a single length `\fboxsep` for the separation of the box content from the box margin (and rule) -- This is easier of course and is also connected to the fact that in earlier times there weren't much length registers at hand just to squander them.

I've stolen the code from `latex.ltx` and changed the settings, using `\fboxhsep` and `\fboxvsep`, at the right places, to provide a solution without any extra package.

Of course, this `\fboxother` won't break over pages. For such things `tcolorbox` etc. is much easier.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter

\newlength{\fboxhsep}
\newlength{\fboxvsep}

\setlength{\fboxhsep}{5\fboxsep}
\setlength{\fboxvsep}{20\fboxsep}


\def\@frameb@xother#1{%
  \@tempdima\fboxrule
  \advance\@tempdima\fboxvsep
  \advance\@tempdima\dp\@tempboxa
  \hbox{%
    \lower\@tempdima\hbox{%
      \vbox{%
        \hrule\@height\fboxrule
        \hbox{%
          \vrule\@width\fboxrule
          #1%
          \vbox{%
            \vskip\fboxvsep
            \box\@tempboxa
            \vskip\fboxvsep}%
          #1%
          \vrule\@width\fboxrule}%
        \hrule\@height\fboxrule}%
    }%
  }%
}


\long\def\fboxother#1{%
  \leavevmode
  \setbox\@tempboxa\hbox{%
    \color@begingroup
    \kern\fboxhsep{#1}\kern\fboxhsep
    \color@endgroup}%
  \@frameb@xother\relax}

\makeatother
\begin{document}
\fboxother{\parbox{\linewidth}{Hello world test example break this line\\
here is a new line just for the example}}
\end{document}
```

**Update**

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter

\newlength{\fboxhsep}
\newlength{\fboxvsep}

\newlength{\fboxtoprule}
\newlength{\fboxbottomrule}
\newlength{\fboxleftrule}
\newlength{\fboxrightrule}



\setlength{\fboxhsep}{5\fboxsep}
\setlength{\fboxvsep}{20\fboxsep}

\setlength{\fboxtoprule}{\fboxrule}
\setlength{\fboxleftrule}{\fboxrule}
\setlength{\fboxrightrule}{\fboxrule}
\setlength{\fboxbottomrule}{\fboxrule}



\def\@frameb@xother#1{%
  \@tempdima\fboxtoprule
  \advance\@tempdima\fboxvsep
  \advance\@tempdima\dp\@tempboxa
  \hbox{%
    \lower\@tempdima\hbox{%
      \vbox{%
        \hrule\@height\fboxtoprule
        \hbox{%
          \vrule\@width\fboxleftrule
          #1%
          \vbox{%
            \vskip\fboxvsep
            \box\@tempboxa
            \vskip\fboxvsep}%
          #1%
          \vrule\@width\fboxrightrule}%
        \hrule\@height\fboxbottomrule}%
    }%
  }%
}


\long\def\fboxother#1{%
  \leavevmode
  \setbox\@tempboxa\hbox{%
    \color@begingroup
    \kern\fboxhsep{#1}\kern\fboxhsep
    \color@endgroup}%
  \@frameb@xother\relax}

\newcommand{\myfbox}[3]{%
  \begingroup
  \setlength{\fboxhsep}{#1}
  \setlength{\fboxvsep}{#2}
  \fboxother{#3}

  \endgroup
}

\makeatother
\begin{document}
\fboxother{\parbox{\linewidth}{Hello world test example break this line\\
here is a new line just for the example}}
\myfbox{1cm}{1.5cm}{\parbox{\linewidth}{Hello world test example break this line \\
here is a new line just for the example}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Most important is vertical space (top and bottom spacing) in my opinion, I am thinking about a command or macro the same as the command in my MWE which takes two arguments:  vertical spacing and `width` length of course. `\myfbox{width}{spacing}{text}`

Comment: @SAM: See the update please

Comment: Of course, the usage with the `\parbox{\linewidth}` produces an overfull hbox